# resolve in_array() parameter warning in Wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, plugins, warnings, jetpack

I'm seeing this error message at the top of my website:

`Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home1/santikac/public_html/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/class.jetpack.php on line 1518`

How do I resolve this warning?

Comment: this means, on your wordpress, you have plugin call "jetpack" who have huge error. If this plugin is not  necessary on your website, just delete it, if is necessary then update it.

Comment: This is helpful. I am no longer seeing the warning message on the dashboard (back end). But I am still seeing the warning message on the website.

Comment: is because plugin is running on frontend (website) only. Just disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `in_array()` accepts two parameters -

1. The string to be matched in the array
2. The array itself

Also, there is an optional parameter -

3. `$strict = FALSE;`

Let's take an example:

```
$valueToSearch = "abc";
$arrayToSearch = array("acb", "abc", "dce");
echo in_array($valueToSearch, $arrayToSearch);
```

If you inspect the warning properly it tells you the method and the line number where the issue is coming. You can navigate to that particular line and try `print_r()` with the variable passed to `in_array()` and resolve the issue. If not, update your question with the outputs of `print_r()`.